# scope in routes.rb not properly working in connection with get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, scope

In my rails 3.2.2 app I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
scope "abc" do
   get "hello/index"
end
```

Which should link "/abc/hello/index" to my index-action in my hello-controller, right?

Instead, I get the error "uninitialized constant Abc"

If I change it to the following

```
scope "abc" do
   match "hello/index", to: "hello#index", via: :get
end
```

it works just fine.

From my understanding of the routing engine, the two should be the same, shouldn't they?

(See e.g.: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints )

Also, if you do a "rails g controller hello index" a route named

```
get "hello/index"
```

is autocreated suggesting that this is the standard way of doing a non-restful get route.

So why can't I scope such a route? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The examples are using the notation `scope "/abc"`, maybe the initial `/` is required.

Comment: nope, no difference when using "/abc". Still "uninitialized constant Abc"